# Oracle Left join give duplicate

Tags: oracle, join, duplicates

I am trying to get all the customers whether they have install service or not from TRANS_TABLE.

NOA- query to get only the MAX product and join again with TRANS_TABLE by email id to get the all the MAX customers details (wwhther they have install service by adding Y OR N, but this query return duplicate with REP Product as well

Below is my Oracel Query which give duplicated

```
with CTE as (SELECT NOA.*, 
       CASE 
         WHEN TRANS_TABLE.product_name LIKE '%Installation%' THEN 'Y' 
         ELSE 'N' 
       END AS Installaion ,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TRANS_TABLE.email_address ORDER BY TRANS_TABLE.email_address) AS rn

FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT email_address         
        FROM  TRANS_TABLE
        WHERE  email_address IS NOT NULL
and pdct_name like '%MAX%'      
               ) NOA 
       LEFT JOIN TRANS_TABLE 
              ON NOA.email_address = TRANS_TABLE.email_address 
              select * from cte where rn='1'
```

[image: Table and the expected result]

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Insert images/links using edit functions.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help:

```
CTE AS (
    SELECT
        NOA.*,
        CASE
            WHEN TRANS_TABLE.PDCT_NAME LIKE '%INSTALLATION%' THEN 'Y' -- case sensitive name is used
            ELSE 'N'
        END AS INSTALLAION,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY TRANS_TABLE.EMAIL_ADDRESS
            ORDER BY
                TRANS_TABLE.EMAIL_ADDRESS
        ) AS RN
    FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                PDCT_NAME,
                EMAIL_ADDRESS
            FROM
                TRANS_TABLE
            WHERE
                EMAIL_ADDRESS IS NOT NULL
                AND PDCT_NAME LIKE '%MAX%'
        ) NOA
        LEFT JOIN TRANS_TABLE ON NOA.EMAIL_ADDRESS = TRANS_TABLE.EMAIL_ADDRESS
        WHERE TRANS_TABLE.PDCT_NAME NOT LIKE '%REP%') -- added this WHERE condition
SELECT
   PDCT_NAME,  EMAIL_ADDRESS, INSTALLAION
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    RN = '1'
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=df4effe4609867be2fad32aaa2c9cb45)

Cheers!!